# Is this 'self isnt defined' error a scope problem?

Tags: python, oop

In my main script I have the following code:

```
class Sequence:

    def __init__(self, colour, text):
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = 5
        self.height = 5
        self.text = text

    def create_window(self, root):
        self.name=tk.Label(root,text=self.text, wdith=self.width, height=self.height, 
        bg=self.colour
        self.name.pack()
```

In my gui script this code is run as

```
Sequence.create_window(self, root)
```

I get the error:

```
Sequence.create_window(self, root) NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Im not really sure how to fix this, does it have do with the scope of the program?

Comment: Please review https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects

Comment: First you need to make an instance of the `Sequence` class. Then you can call the `create_window` method of the instance, without passing `self` as an argument.

Comment: I mean, yes, it is fundamentally because you are trying to use a variable which is not defined in that scope. If you had a function, `def plus_two(x): return x +2` what would you expect `plus_two(x)` to work? No, it would throw a NameError because there is no `x` in the caller. But also, you fundamentally need to understand OOP, these are methods in a class, the class is supposed to be *instantiated* first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize an object first:

```
class Sequence:

    def __init__(self, colour, text):
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = 5
        self.height = 5
        self.text = text

    def create_window(self, root):
        self.name=tk.Label(root,text=self.text, wdith=self.width, height=self.height, 
        bg=self.colour)
        self.name.pack()

sequence = Sequence("blue", "test")
sequence.create_window(root)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get another error saying 'root' isn't defined.

Comment: Yeah, obviously. Because you have to define root first :) But I don't know what root is. Have a look at the documentation please :)

Answer (score 0):

root is a variable defined in create_window method

`tk.Label` need to be placed in either window or frame which is passed as first argument.

```py
import sys
if sys.version_info.major == 2
  # for python 2
  import Tkinter as tk
else
  # for python 3
  import tkinter as tk

class Sequence:

    def __init__(self, colour, text):
        self.colour = colour
        self.width = 5
        self.height = 5
        self.text = text

    def create_window(self, root):
        self.name=tk.Label(root, text=self.text, wdith=self.width, height=self.height, 
        bg=self.colour)
        self.name.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()

    sequence = Sequence("blue", "test")
    sequence.create_window(root)

    root.mainloop()
```